# How to do an insert in the database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, indentation, mysql-python

I have a Python script that does the Moodle version check.
After checking the Moodle version I would like to insert into the database but I am getting the following error:

```
line 337
mycursor = db.cursor()
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

This is the code that using and with problems:

```
import import mysql.connector

...

def printversion(version):
if version != 0:
    print ("\nVersion found via " + version.split(';')[2] + " : Moodle " +  version.split(';')[0])
    vuln = version.split(';')[0]
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="admin", passwd="", database="test")
    mycursor = db.cursor() 
    insertQuery = """INSERT INTO moodle (id,payload) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
    mycursor.execute(insertQuery, ('',vuln))
    db.commit()  
    db.close()
    return version.split(';')[0].replace("v","")
    
print ("\nVersion not found")
return False
```

The error reported is about code indentation, but I don't know how to solve this problem to insert versioning results in the database.

Is code with indentation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeNZc.png)

Comment: you need to indent after `def printversion(version):`. Basically after `:` in python you need to indent everything that is supposed to be part of the block. Here all the lines from `if version !=0:` to `return False` need one more indent

Comment: Don't be creative or opinionated when it comes to indentation. Follow the standards and make everyone's life easier - you, future you, others using your code, us. Standard indentation for Python is 4 spaces everywhere. Just that you're allowed to diverge doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: My error:

line 335
    vuln = version.split(';')[0]
                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a slight misunderstanding here, in any function in python you need to provide an indentation(tab) before you start writing any code,

i.e. structure is

```
def your_functionname(parameters)
    < you code here >
```

So, in a correct way, your code should look like this

```
...

def printversion(version):
    if version != 0:
        print ("\nVersion found via " + version.split(';')[2] + " : Moodle " +  
        version.split(';')[0])
        vuln = version.split(';')[0]
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="admin", passwd="", 
        database="test")
        mycursor = db.cursor() 
        insertQuery = """INSERT INTO moodle (id,payload) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
        mycursor.execute(insertQuery, ('',vuln))
        db.commit()  
        db.close()
        return version.split(';')[0].replace("v","")
        
    print ("\nVersion not found")
    return False
```

Comment: Polymath, thanks very much for help.
The script its work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires the section after the function definition to be indented.

So instead of this,

```
def printversion(version):
if version != 0:
    print ("\nVersion found via " + version.split(';')[2] + " : Moodle " +  version.split(';')[0])
    vuln = version.split(';')[0]
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="admin", passwd="", database="test")
    mycursor = db.cursor() 
    insertQuery = """INSERT INTO moodle (id,payload) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
    mycursor.execute(insertQuery, ('',vuln))
    db.commit()  
    db.close()
    return version.split(';')[0].replace("v","")
```

You should have this,

```
def printversion(version):
    if version != 0:
        print ("\nVersion found via " + version.split(';')[2] + " : Moodle " +  version.split(';')[0])
        vuln = version.split(';')[0]
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="admin", passwd="", database="test")
        mycursor = db.cursor() 
        insertQuery = """INSERT INTO moodle (id,payload) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
        mycursor.execute(insertQuery, ('',vuln))
        db.commit()  
        db.close()
        return version.split(';')[0].replace("v","")
```

I don't know the intention of your code, but looks like you might want to include an `else` statement as well,

```
    else:
        print ("\nVersion not found")
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

Just tab the line
if version != 0:

Ident only this line

Comment: I try, but not work. This is error: line 335
    vuln = version.split(';')[0]
                                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level